# PyDev Hangs RCP App

Tags: eclipse-rcp, pydev

We include PyDev in one of our internal RCP applications and it's been well behaved for a while now. Recently I've upraded to 6.3.1 of PyDev, and I have noticed that PyDev appears to be hanging my RCP app when the app is launched in the background. Anytime I launch our RPC with & (background job in unix), we get the app suspended when anything PyDev related happens. As long as we are running in the foreground, things go well, but if the app is running in the background, we believe PyDev operations are causing the app to suspend:

"[1]  + Suspended (tty output)"

- Situations when hangs occur:

  - App is running in the background and

    - we try to set the PyDev interpreter (instant hang)
    - Occasional hangs when splash screen is up and a org.python.pydev plugin is being loaded.
    - If any Python editors were open, if we make it to the app running, the open editor will eventually hang the RCP app in less than a minute.

Foregrounding the app always fixes, but it's irritating. I work in a heavily IT controlled environment and our linux http access to the outside world is well shielded. I'm not sure how, but there's plenty of external sites we can't get do (makes everything in open source land very hard to deal with).

- So far I have tried (from Stackoverflow and Google):

  - stty -tostop  (did not work.  tostop was never set anyway)
  - Dpydev.funding.hide=1 (did not work)
  - Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true (did not work)
  - hacking preferences to tell PyDev not to show me popups (did not work)
  - Piping /dev/null into my app (did not work)
  - Telling my IT staff "stuff is weird" (did not work and IT had a good laugh)

I have no idea what to do. Telling our users they have to run the application in the foreground if they are using Python scripts is kind of lame and reflects on us, so I'd rather not do that.

Any ideas?

Code completion works BTW. So the majority of hits I get about PyDev hanging do not apply here.  We've seen this behavior now with PyDev 5.2 (our old version with Mars) and 6.3.1 (newest version with Neon).  So I don't think it's version dependent.

If there's any hacks I can do to PyDev to say "please stop causing my terminal to suspend my RCP app" that would really help.

It's my first post and I have spent most of the time formatting stuff to fool Stackoverflow into beveling that I have not posted code.

Edit:

The log files do not clearly indicate what is happening, although we do see these messages (but they don't seem to correlate 1:1 to the hangs/suspensions)

!MESSAGE The python client still hasn't connected back to the eclipse java vm (will retry...)
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: The python client still hasn't connected back to the eclipse java vm (will retry...)

!ENTRY org.python.pydev.shared_core 4 4 2018-04-12 14:06:54.444
!MESSAGE Attempt: 2 of 5 failed, trying again...(socket connected: still null)
!STACK 0
java.lang.RuntimeException: Attempt: 2 of 5 failed, trying again...(socket connected: still null)

Comment: Please get a stack dump on when the hang happens and report it to the pydev tracker. See: https://wiki.eclipse.org/How_to_report_a_deadlock for how to properly get the needed info... without that info, it's only a shot in the dark (it's hard to know if the fault is with your rcp app or with pydev or something else entirely from your report and without further info it's not really possible to do anything).

Comment: The stack dump is too big to enter into a ticket.  I have two stack dumps now, one where the RCP app is hung during the Splash screen and another when the app has been able to load, but hangs when I try to access PyDev Perspective/Edtiors.  Do you want me to e-mail these to you since I can't include them in a PyDev Tracker ticket?

Comment: Okay, I added a ticket with an abbreviated stack trace. Ticket #909: PyDev 6.3.1 Hangs RCP App